# it does not allow me to select buttons if something is entered in textbox

Tags: jquery, html, button, textbox

In my application what happens is that the user chooses a button by clicking on the (open Grid) link and selecting a button. Then what happens is that a set of buttons appear below depending on what the user has chosen. The user is supose to determine how many answers he wants to select in the text box (in other words how many buttons does the user want to select). For example if the user enters "2" in the textbox, then the user can only select 2 buttons below. The problem is that if the user types in a number in the text box, then it would not allow the user to select a button, (a button is selected if the color of the button turns green). but if I remove the number which is in the text box, then if I click on a button it comes up with an alert message stating that you should determine the number of answers you want, this is correct.

So why is it not allowing me to select any buttons if there is a number inside the "Number of Answers" textbox?

Code is in jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pSy97/12/)

Thank You

Comment: there is an error `currenttotal is not defined` rather there are more than one errors, have you inspected the firebug console

Answer (score 0):

Open the browser console. When you click a button, you'll see the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: currenttotal is not defined
```

It's thrown by this line of code:

```
console.log(currenttotal);
```

[image]

---

There's another problem which appears to be preventing `currenttotal`'s initialization:

[image]

---

If I put a breakpoint at this line: `var letter = $('#numberAnswerTxt').val();` (inside of `getButtons`), I can see that the variable `"letter"` is a string that looks like `"3"`. Strings do not have a property named `String`, so `letter.String` is undefined. This is why the `TypeError: Cannot call method 'fromCharCode' of undefined` is thrown.

So I *think* that `for` loop should go something like this:

```
for(var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) { // iterate over character codes for A to Z
    var letter = String.fromCharCode(i);
    document.getElementById("answer" + letter).className = "answerBtnsOff";
}
```

Since you're using jQuery you can make the loop body more concise:

```
for(var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) { // iterate over character codes for A to Z
    var letter = String.fromCharCode(i);
    $("#answer" + letter).prop("class", "answerBtnsOff");
}
```

---

#### Now it works

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/ZCehW/

Comment: so I am guessing I need to move console.log(currenttotal)?

Comment: I've added a bunch more to my answer. Have a look.

Comment: There is a problem though and hence why I did it letter.String.fromCharCode(i) in first place. The problem is now that if I select for example button "4" from gird, it should display buttons "A", "B", "C" and "D", but if something is entered in the Number for answers textbox and lets say I want to select button "1" from grid, it should change the display to only show button "A" but as you can see it does not change the display.

Comment: Okay... well, I don't fully understand the behavior you're aiming for, but I can tell you two things: **1.** `letter.String.fromCharCode(i)` will throw an error, so you should probably not use it. **2.** You need to change your code to reflect the desired behavior.

Comment: The behaviour is that the buttons in grid determines the number of options you require so for example if I choose button "1" from the grid, it will only display button "A" as that this is the only option, it user selects button "2" from grid, then it would display buttons "A" and "B" as these are two options and etc

Comment: Did you see my jsFiddle link? That exact behavior is what I see.

Comment: Yes I have, it works if nothing is entered in the "Number of Answers" Textbox but if you enter something in the textbox then it doesn't work. Do this example in your jsfiddle, select button "1" from grid, this should display button "A" below, then enter in "1" in the "Number of Answers" textbox, now select button "2" from the grid, it should display buttons "A" and "B" below but it doesn't, it still only display button "A"